# Using existing html layout in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, templating

This is my first time trying to make a login page.  What I want to be able to do is take an existing html and put the login control on that page.  I realize I can't take the html and drop asp controls on to it.  My question is how do I use the existing HTML layout as the template for my new aspx page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get the source for the existing page ( View in a browser -> Right Click-> View  source -> Select All -> Copy)
2) Create a new aspx page; delete everything after the <%@ Page %> directive
3) Paste your HTML source from the HTML page.
4) Switch to design view of the aspx page, and delete whatever you dont need, add your login controls.

Comment: When I add a new item are you referring to addining a new HTML page?

Comment: Mike, when you click new, make sure its a new .aspx page

Comment: i dont get that option, the other way that I can find to get a new .aspx page is to select webform

Comment: Yea, that will create the aspx page and from that you would be pasting the html into

Comment: not a new HTML page, a new aspx page; it will show up as "Web Form" in your "Add New" window

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty asp.net project and then copy the HTML into the new page and modify it to work with the controls you are dropping into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist a layout across multiple pages and I'm not sure that's what you are looking for, then the best thing to do is to store the html for layout in a master page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="HeaderContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">//add in html to setup your header</div>
  <div id="content"><asp:ContnetPlaceHolder ID="Content"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></div>
  <div id="footer">//add in html to setup the footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```